# Swagger/drf_yasg: either schema or type are required for Parameter object (not both)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I have the following path:

```
path('path/<int:object_id>',
     function,
     name='function'),
```

The way it is, drf_yasg is generating the documentation for `object_id` as if it as a string:

[image: drf_yasg string]

So I decided to manually input the information in the `swagger_auto_schema` decorator:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
    method='PATCH',
    manual_parameters=[
        openapi.Parameter('object_id', openapi.IN_PATH, required=True, description='Object ID'),
        # query parameters
    ],
    # operation_description, responses, etc
)
@api_view(['PATCH'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def function(request, object_id)
```

However, by doing this, drf_yasg raises the error `either schema or type are required for Parameter object (not both)!`, and I can't fix this unless I remove the `object_id` path parameter form the decorator

Anyway, I'm interested in being able to explicitly descibe my path parameter in the decorator instead of letting drf_yasg doing this by myself

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should provide  the schema attribute with the desired data type for the object_id parameter.

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
        method='PATCH',
        manual_parameters=[
            openapi.Parameter('object_id', openapi.IN_PATH, schema=openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER), description='Object ID'),
           
        ],)
```

Comment: Noticed just by looking at your answer that I was missing the `type` field. I added it and worked. For clarification, using `schema=openapi.Schema()` is raising an `AssertionError: schema can only be applied to a body Parameter, not None`, just using `type` is enough